# How to replace a Mergefield with an image in VB.Net OPEN XML

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml

i'm using OPEN XML to replace some mergefields in a Word Document, with text works just fine but i can't make it work for images. here is the code:

```
If textElement.Text.Contains("«codBa»") Then
                        Dim textPlaceHolder As Text = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants(Of Text)() _
                        .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Text = "«codBa»")

                        If textPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then
                            Console.WriteLine("¡Marcador de texto no encontrado!")
                        Else
                            Dim parent = textPlaceHolder.Parent

                            If Not (TypeOf parent Is Run) Then 
                                Console.Out.WriteLine("El padre no es un Run")
                            Else
                                

                                Dim myBarcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(oEnvio.numEnvio, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128)
                                Dim myBarcodeImage As Image = myBarcode.Image
                                Dim runParent As Run = DirectCast(parent, Run)
                                runParent.InsertAfter(myBarcodeImage, textPlaceHolder)

                                textPlaceHolder.Remove()
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
```

I've also tried to save it as base64 but i dont know how to make the word template to translate the base64 into an image